# R plots : using RGB values from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rgb

I am having trouble using RGB colours present in a dataframe.

```
color.table
    V1  V2  V3    
    1   Red 255,0,0
    2   Orange Red  255,69,0
    3   LimeGreen   50,205,50
    4   Green   0,128,0
    5   DarkGreen   0,100,0
    6   GreenYellow 194,225,5
    7   Yellow  255,255,0
    8   Aquamarine  102,205,170
    9   PaleTurquoise   138,145,208
    10  IndianRed   205,92,92
    11  DarkSalmon  233,150,122
    12  DarkKhaki   189,183,107
    13  Silver  128,128,128
    14  Gainsboro   192,192,192
    15  White   255,255,255
```

It seems that I cannot use the RGB present in this dataframe.

```
barplot(seq(1:15) , col=color.table$V3 )
Error in rect(y1, x1, y2, x2, ...) : 
  invalid color specification "255,0,0"
```

Even if I try to convert the RGB in Hexadecimal value, there is something odd.

```
rgb(color.table$V3[1], 50, m=255)
Error in rgb(color.table$V3[1], 50, m = 255) : 
  argument "blue" is missing, with no default
```

Where as this works:

```
> rgb(255,0,0, 50, m=255)
[1] "#FF000032"
```

There is something fishy here, but I can't put my finger on it. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: When you look up the documentation at `?rgb`, can you explain which arguments you think you are passing values to when you run `rgb(color.table$V5[1], 50, m=255)`?

Comment: I think I am passing this : `rgb(255,0,0, 50, m=255)`

Comment: Well, `color.table$V5[1]` is just a single value, not three. So you've essentially done `rgb(red = color.table$V5[1],green = 50,maxColorValues = 1)`, due to positional and then partial argument matching.

Comment: I actually did not mean anything by that. I was trying to help you get there yourself, but it wasn't working.

Comment: Done! `list = unlist(strsplit(all$V5[1],",") )`
then `rgb(list[1], list[2], list[3], 50, m=255)
[1] "#FF000032"` Maybe not very elegant, but I got there. Thanks joran for getting me there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `rgb` function to extract colors from the `V3` variable:

```
cols <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(color.table$V3), ","), function(x) {
  rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], m=255)
})
cols
#  [1] "#FF0000" "#FF4500" "#32CD32" "#008000" "#006400" "#C2E105" "#FFFF00" "#66CDAA" "#8A91D0"
# [10] "#CD5C5C" "#E9967A" "#BDB76B" "#808080" "#C0C0C0" "#FFFFFF"
```

Now you can add these colors as a new column in your data frame, pass them to plotting functions through the col argument, etc.